# MySQL trigger reports error when inserting

Tags: mysql

I've created a trigger on a table to insert values into one of the columns in the same table after a row is inserted. What gets inserted into the column depends on a set of validations as you can see from the below code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `FMY_NUM` AFTER INSERT ON `table_1`
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE LC_VAR INTEGER;
   CASE 
      WHEN table_1. txt_avl>= 7 THEN SET LC_VAR = 5;
      WHEN table_1.txt_avl > 9 AND table_1.txt_avl < 5000 THEN SET LC_VAR = 3;
      WHEN table_1.txt_avl > 11 AND table_1.txt_avl < 3000 THEN SET LC_VAR = 2;
      ELSE SET LC_VAR = 1;
   END CASE;
   UPDATE table_1 set table_1.v1order = LC_VAR WHERE v1Pkey = NEW.v1Pkey;   

END
```

The problem I have is, when I run an insert into table statement, I get the error,

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1109 - Unknown table 'table_1' in field list
```

I've never worked on triggers in MySQL before. Trying to get my head around this. Could someone please help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your trigger.

Firstly, the error about `Unknown table 'table_1' in field list` refers to your use of `table_1.txt_avl` in the `WHEN` clauses of your `CASE` statement.  It seems you want to access the value of `txt_avl` in the row being inserted, and to do that, you use `new.txt_avl` instead.

This change alone however isn't enough to get the trigger to work.  If you make this change to your trigger, you will get the following error (or at least I did, anyway):

> ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

The problem here is the use of an `UPDATE` statement that updates `table_1` within an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the same table.  If you want to set the value of a column in the new row, you can do this by setting the new value of the column, using `SET new.v1order = LC_VAR;`.  However, you must also change the trigger to fire `BEFORE INSERT` instead of `AFTER INSERT`.
You can't change a column like this in an `AFTER` trigger, as by the time your trigger has been called it is too late - the data has already hit the database.

Once this is done the trigger appears to work.  Here's a quick session where I create a table and your trigger, insert some data and verify that the trigger fired and did something:

```
MariaDB [blah]> create table table_1 (v1order int, v1Pkey int, txt_avl int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

MariaDB [blah]> DELIMITER $$
MariaDB [blah]> CREATE TRIGGER `FMY_NUM` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_1`
    ->    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    ->    DECLARE LC_VAR INTEGER;
    ->    CASE 
    ->       WHEN new.txt_avl>= 7 THEN SET LC_VAR = 5;
    ->       WHEN new.txt_avl > 9 AND new.txt_avl < 5000 THEN SET LC_VAR = 3;
    ->       WHEN new.txt_avl > 11 AND new.txt_avl < 3000 THEN SET LC_VAR = 2;
    ->       ELSE SET LC_VAR = 1;
    ->    END CASE;
    ->    SET new.v1order = LC_VAR;
    -> END;
    -> $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

MariaDB [blah]> DELIMITER ;
MariaDB [blah]> insert into table_1 (v1Pkey, txt_avl) values (1, 8);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [blah]> select * from table_1;
+---------+--------+---------+
| v1order | v1Pkey | txt_avl |
+---------+--------+---------+
|       5 |      1 |       8 |
+---------+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hello,Many many thanks for the solution. I get a syntax error with this now!! MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER FMY_NUM BEFORE INSERT ON table_1 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE LC_VAR INTEGER; CASE WHEN new.txt_avl>= 7 THEN SET LC_VAR = 5; WHEN new.txt_avl > 9 AND new.txt_avl < 5000 THEN SET LC_VAR = 3; WHEN new.txt_avl > 11 AND new.txt_avl < 3000 THEN SET LC_VAR = 2; ELSE SET LC_VAR = 1; END CASE; SET new.v1order = LC_VAR; END;

Comment: The above is what I've got. I removed the semicolon after integer declaration & changed WHEN new.txt_avl>= 7to new.txt_avl >=7. Even the earlier running trigger seems to error out while creating. ANy guidance please?

Comment: Found the problem. It was me being dumb there. While using PHPMyAdmin,  the SQL text editor doesn't recognize the option "DELIMITER $$" at the start & DELIMITER; at the end. One has to set the delimiter though & the way to that is change the DELIMITER from the default of ;; to say $$ in the small box right below the SQL editor       =>          [ Delimiter  ]Show this query here againRetain query boxRollback when finished

Comment: Thank you Luke once again. Totally appreciate your pitching in & blowing the problem

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your database doesn't have any table named as table_1

Comment: It's definitely there. I can view it through PHPMyAdmin GUI & also describe the table.Any help in re-writing the PLSQL trigger would also benefit me please.